# Java fade in and out of images

Tags: java, image, swing, animation, transparency

I am trying to learn how to fade in and out images into another image or from another image.  So, if I have 2 images, and 1 is being displayed at the moment, I want to display another image in the background and fade the first image out into the 2nd image.  OR, I want to set the focus on the new image and slowly fade it in over the 1st image, then stop displaying the 1st one.

I'm not sure how:

1. to set focus, if even needed.
2. I can fade in if I change the alpha to 0 and increment up and only draw one image, however I cannot get it to fade out either with any variation of this code.  (i.e. commenting out one image to draw).

Edit:  Really, all I'm worried about is being able to have 2 images and make the image currently being displayed slowly disappear into the 2nd image.  How that is accomplished doesn't need to be with this.

Here is a code sample I'm messing with:

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class FadeIn extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private Image imagem;
    private Image image2;
    private Timer timer;
    private float alpha = 1f;

    public FadeIn() {
        imagem = (new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
             "/resources/1stImage.jpg"))).getImage();
        image2 = (new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
             "/resources/2ndImage.jpg"))).getImage();    
        timer = new Timer(20, this);
        timer.start();
    }
    // here you define alpha 0f to 1f

    public FadeIn(float alpha) {
        imagem = (new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
             "/resources/1stImage.jpg"))).getImage();
        this.alpha = alpha;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawImage(imagem, 0, 0, 400, 300, null);
        g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER,
                alpha));
        g2d.drawImage(image2, 0, 0, 400, 300, null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Fade out");
        frame.add(new FadeIn());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(420, 330);
        // frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        alpha += -0.01f;
        if (alpha <= 0) {
            alpha = 0;
            timer.stop();
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "setFocus"?

Comment: Basically draw one image in the background, and another in front of it.  Then fade the top image out using the timer.  Instead of a white background it would be the bottom image.  I've been able to do it if I just fill in a rectangle on the screen, but I can't set the image in the background.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically, what this does is use the same alpha value, fading in from 0-1 and then using the same alpha, going from 1-0, allowing the two images to cross fade over each other...

[image: Fading]

The magic basically, happens in the `paintComponent`, where the image coming in using the `alpha` value and the outgoing image uses `1f - alpha`.

Switching between the two images is actually a the same process, expect the `inImage` is swapped for the `outImage`

The timing is little different.  Instead of a straight move from `0-1` using a standard delta (ie `0.01` for example), this uses a time based algorithm.

That is, I use a timer which ticks every 40 milliseconds or so, it then does a calculation based on the amount of time the timer has being running and calculates the `alpha` value accordingly...

This allows you to change the amount of time the animation will take, but also provides a slightly better algorithm that takes into account the passive nature of Swings rendering engine...

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class FadeImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FadeImage();
    }

    public FadeImage() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public static final long RUNNING_TIME = 2000;

        private BufferedImage inImage;
        private BufferedImage outImage;

        private float alpha = 0f;
        private long startTime = -1;

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                inImage = ImageIO.read(new File("/path/to/inImage"));
                outImage = ImageIO.read(new File("/path/to/outImage"));
            } catch (IOException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }

            final Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (startTime < 0) {
                        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    } else {

                        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        long duration = time - startTime;
                        if (duration >= RUNNING_TIME) {
                            startTime = -1;
                            ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                            alpha = 0f;
                        } else {
                            alpha = 1f - ((float) duration / (float) RUNNING_TIME);
                        }
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
            });
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    alpha = 0f;
                    BufferedImage tmp = inImage;
                    inImage = outImage;
                    outImage = tmp;
                    timer.start();
                }

            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(
                            Math.max(inImage.getWidth(), outImage.getWidth()), 
                            Math.max(inImage.getHeight(), outImage.getHeight()));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(alpha));
            int x = (getWidth() - inImage.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - inImage.getHeight()) / 2;
            g2d.drawImage(inImage, x, y, this);

            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(1f - alpha));
            x = (getWidth() - outImage.getWidth()) / 2;
            y = (getHeight() - outImage.getHeight()) / 2;
            g2d.drawImage(outImage, x, y, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, I understand what you are saying.  I am going to try implement this in the manner you specified quickly.

Comment: You can do this using a straight delta, I just find a time based one provides a better result ;)

Comment: Haha, well you are more experienced than I am so I will take your word for it :p   I got this working perfectly after I figured out how to load an image from resources using the ImageIO.read.  I had never used a BufferedImage before.  Would this work with a plane old 'Image' type?

Comment: Well, this looks amazing either way.  Best answer to any question I've had on stack overflow, so I thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a easy and short most developers using java code for image fade.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.RescaleOp;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/**
 *
 * @author ADMIN
 */
public class ImageFade extends JFrame {

    ImageFade() {
        setLayout(null);

        JLabel l = new JLabel();
        l.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 96);
        add(l);

        Thread tp = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int amp = 0; amp <= 500; amp++) {
                    try {
                        sleep(1);
                        try {
                            BufferedImage bim = ImageIO.read(new File("src/image/fade/image.png"));
                            BufferedImage nbim = new BufferedImage(bim.getWidth(), bim.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                            Graphics2D createGraphics = nbim.createGraphics();
                            createGraphics.drawImage(bim, null, 0, 0);
                            RescaleOp r = new RescaleOp(new float[]{1f, 1f, 1f, (float) amp / 500}, new float[]{0, 0, 0, 0}, null);
                            BufferedImage filter = r.filter(nbim, null);
                            l.setIcon(new ImageIcon(filter));
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            System.err.println(ex);
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        tp.start();

        setUndecorated(true);
        setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        setSize(100, 96);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImageFade fr = new ImageFade();
    }
}
```

in this code you can see a thread code. in the thread this image will fade in.

the used image is stack overflow web page's logo image.

only by shown code the image will fade in.

```
Thread tp = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int amp = 0; amp <= 500; amp++) {
            try {
                sleep(1);
                try {
                    BufferedImage bim = ImageIO.read(new File("src/image/fade/image.png"));
                    BufferedImage nbim = new BufferedImage(bim.getWidth(), bim.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                    Graphics2D createGraphics = nbim.createGraphics();
                    createGraphics.drawImage(bim, null, 0, 0);
                    RescaleOp r = new RescaleOp(new float[]{1f, 1f, 1f, (float) amp / 500}, new float[]{0, 0, 0, 0}, null);
                    BufferedImage filter = r.filter(nbim, null);
                    l.setIcon(new ImageIcon(filter));
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                      System.err.println(ex);
                  }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
};
tp.start();
```

This code is very simple to use.

This is not from any book, internet or etc. It is developed by me.

A normal image is not able to change alpha. By code : `BufferedImage nbim = new BufferedImage(bim.getWidth(), bim.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);` the image will convert to ARGB - Alpha, Red, Green, Blue (R,G,B,A) image.

So you can change the alpha of a image.