# Fading an image in from black

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, fade

I'm working in Java and I'm trying to show an image, faded in from black.

Currently I have two images stacked on top of each other: The image I want to show and a black image that's the size of the `JFrame` that I gradually decrease the alpha of with a loop.

This way isn't aesthetically pleasing and is hard to modify.  Is there any built-in way in Java to get this effect and maybe have more control over with is shown?

Comment: For better answers 1) show us how you're currently doing this, using an image available from online sources, posting [mcve] code with your question, and 2) explain in detail how your current code's behavior is not working well for you.

Comment: [That's one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346661/java-fade-in-and-out-of-images/20347600#20347600) - While it's cross fading, the basic principle remains

Answer (score 0):

RescaleOp is your friend, you can try something like, not sure about offset value

```
while (scale <0.8){
  float scale = 0.2f;
  float offset = 15f;
  RescaleOp rescaleOp = new RescaleOp(scale, offset, null);
  rescaleOp.filter(imageOriginal, imageDark);
  scale = scale+0.2;
  some code for paint and delay
}
at last paint imageOriginal
```

Comment: Such a while loop as this risks freezing the GUI's event loop. This is Swing and so he should use a SwingTimer.

Comment: There are many ways, most usable, in my opinion, is to have separate thread for resizing, that calls invokelater for repaint - this allows you to calculate new image and draw allready calced one in one time, but you can in any time switch to invokeandwait if you need to sync your processing time with drawing time to, for example, lower memory usage (1 buffer instead of 2). Anyway it is his choise how to handle tasks in threads, rescaleop is just a way to fade in-out :-)