# How to make 3 images fade in and fade out in JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, fade

My question is how do i make first image dissappear then sec image come in the it vanish then come the third image. i tried to alter here and there but nothing work. it all come out at once. can someone tell me which part should i alter?

```
  import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
  import java.awt.Graphics;
  import java.awt.Graphics2D;
  import java.awt.Image;
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;
  import javax.swing.Timer;

  public class FadeOutImage2 extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

  Image myImage = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\NUR\\Pictures\\FLOWER1.jpg").getImage();
  Image myImage2 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\NUR\\Pictures\\FLOWER2.jpg").getImage();
  Image myImage3 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\NUR\\Pictures\\FLOWER3.jpg").getImage();

  Timer timer = new Timer (50, this); //setting time to fade
  private float alpha = 1f; //alpha value on channel

  public FadeOutImage2(){
     timer.start();
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g){
     super.paint(g);

     Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
     Graphics2D g2d2 = (Graphics2D)g;
     Graphics2D g2d3 = (Graphics2D)g;


g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER,alpha));  
g2d2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER,alpha));
g2d3.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER,alpha));

g2d.drawImage(myImage, 10,10, null); //coordinate
g2d2.drawImage(myImage2, 10,10, null);
g2d3.drawImage(myImage3, 10,10, null);
   }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      alpha += -0.01f;
      if(alpha<=0){
         alpha=0;
         timer.stop();}

      repaint();
  }

public static void main(String[] args){
     JFrame frame = new JFrame("Fade Out");
     frame.add(new FadeOutImage2());

     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setSize(1500,1500);
     frame.setVisible(true);
 }
 }
```

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346661/java-fade-in-and-out-of-images/20347600#20347600) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119221/java-fade-in-and-out-two-jpanels-at-the-same-time/34123681#34123681)

Answer (score 3):

## Theory...

Okay, so based on your requirement, my first suggest is to focus on fading a single image in and out. If you can understand how to do that, then fading three images in out (one after the other) is much simpler.

Animation is the illusion of change over time. So, you first need someway to change the state of the `alpha` over a period of time.  Because Swing is both single threaded and not thread safe, this leaves you with one basic choice, a Swing `Timer`.

This generates updates at regular intervals which are triggers within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, making it safe to use with Swing and to update the UI from within.

Because of the variances in hardware (and OS's), I'd avoid a fixed rate fade (that is, where you apply a fixed `delta` to the `alpha` and repeat until your reach your `target`). This approach can produce undesirable results on different systems.

From my experience, a time based solution generally produces more consistent results.  A time based approach states that the animation will run over a specified time period, on each tick of the `Timer`, we calculate the amount progression and apply that to our state (we know we need to go from 0-1 to fade an image in, so it's easy to calculate the state based on the progression)

## Base implementation...

That all sounds find in practice, but how do we actually apply it.  Because the solution isn't always simple, I'd focus on making a dedicated class to perform the operation.

```
public class FadePane extends JPanel {
    
    private BufferedImage source;
    private Timer timer;
    
    private float alpha = 1.0f;
    
    private int duration = 2000; // 2 seconds
    private Long startTime;
    
    private boolean fadeOut = false;
    
    private FadeListener fadeListener;
    
    public FadePane(BufferedImage source) {
        this.source = source;
        timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (startTime == null) {
                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    fadeStarted();
                }
                long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                alpha = (float)diff / (float)duration;
                if (alpha > 1.0) {
                    timer.stop();
                    alpha = 1.0f;
                    fadeCompleted();
                }
                if (fadeOut) {
                    alpha = 1.0f - alpha;
                }
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }
    
    public void setFadeListener(FadeListener listener) {
        fadeListener = listener;
    }

    public boolean isFadeOut() {
        return fadeOut;
    }
    
    protected void fadeStarted() {
        if (fadeListener != null) {
            fadeListener.fadeStarted(this);
        }
    }

    protected void fadeCompleted() {
        if (fadeListener != null) {
            fadeListener.fadeCompleted(this);
        }
    }
    
    public void setSource(BufferedImage img) {
        source = img;
    }
    
    public void reset() {
        timer.stop();
        alpha = 0;
        startTime = null;
    }
    
    public void fadeIn() {
        reset();
        fadeOut = false;
        timer.start();
    }
    
    public void fadeOut() {
        reset();
        fadeOut = true;
        timer.start();
    }
    
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return source == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());
    }
    
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, alpha));
        int x = (getWidth() - source.getWidth()) / 2;
        int y = (getHeight() - source.getHeight()) / 2;
        g2d.drawImage(source, x, y, this);
        g2d.dispose();
    }
    
}
```

The `FadePane` takes a `source` image and, depending on which method you call, will fade it in or out over a period of 2 seconds.

You can re-use the `FadePane` by simply changing the `source` image via the `setSource` method and fading the new image in or out, depending on the desired result you're after.

The `FadePane` also provides an observer, which is notified when the fade operation is started and completed...

```
public interface FadeListener {
    public void fadeStarted(FadePane pane);
    public void fadeCompleted(FadePane pane);
}
```

This could be used to change the state of the UI (disable/enable functionality) as well as switch the image when you want to

## Runnable Example...

This example simple allows a user to fade the same image in and out, but it wouldn't be hard to generate a `List` of images which which are changed through the `FadeListener`

[image: Fade]

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    BufferedImage source = ImageIO.read(...);
                    FadePane fadePane = new FadePane(source);
                    JButton btn = new JButton("Fade");
                    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        private boolean fadeOut = true;
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            if (fadeOut) {
                                fadePane.fadeOut();
                            } else {
                                fadePane.fadeIn();
                            }
                            fadeOut = !fadeOut;
                        }
                    });

                    fadePane.setFadeListener(new FadeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void fadeStarted(FadePane pane) {
                            btn.setEnabled(false);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void fadeCompleted(FadePane pane) {
                            // Set next image and start the
                            // fade process again
                            btn.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    });

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.add(fadePane);
                    frame.add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public interface FadeListener {
        public void fadeStarted(FadePane pane);
        public void fadeCompleted(FadePane pane);
    }

    public class FadePane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage source;
        private Timer timer;

        private float alpha = 1.0f;

        private int duration = 2000; // 2 seconds
        private Long startTime;

        private boolean fadeOut = false;

        private FadeListener fadeListener;

        public FadePane(BufferedImage source) {
            this.source = source;
            timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (startTime == null) {
                        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        fadeStarted();
                    }
                    long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                    alpha = (float)diff / (float)duration;
                    if (alpha > 1.0) {
                        timer.stop();
                        alpha = 1.0f;
                        fadeCompleted();
                    }
                    if (fadeOut) {
                        alpha = 1.0f - alpha;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        public void setFadeListener(FadeListener listener) {
            fadeListener = listener;
        }

        protected void fadeStarted() {
            if (fadeListener != null) {
                fadeListener.fadeStarted(this);
            }
        }

        protected void fadeCompleted() {
            if (fadeListener != null) {
                fadeListener.fadeCompleted(this);
            }
        }

        public void setSource(BufferedImage img) {
            source = img;
        }

        public void reset() {
            timer.stop();
            alpha = 0;
            startTime = null;
        }

        public boolean isFadeOut() {
            return fadeOut;
        }

        public void fadeIn() {
            reset();
            fadeOut = false;
            timer.start();
        }

        public void fadeOut() {
            reset();
            fadeOut = true;
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return source == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, alpha));
            int x = (getWidth() - source.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - source.getHeight()) / 2;
            g2d.drawImage(source, x, y, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```